# How do I programmatically access a feature's symbol property in a schematic layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, symbology, schematics

I am building a simple app that changes the size of the symbol of the selected feature. Is this possible? Here is a simple case for a selected feature:

```
public void onClick(){

IFeature spliceClosure = _app.splice.load(OID);

// access the symbology

// change the size

//refresh the active view
}
```

In reality this app is going to be used with schematic features. How do I access their symbology and change the size of it? I am trying to scale and rotate the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this done, I have accessed the symbol thanks all.

```
private void ArrangeCrossSetionView(IEnumSchematicInMemoryFeature containerElements, IGeoFeatureLayer geoFtr, ISchematicLayer schematicLayer) {
        ISchematicInMemoryFeature feature;
        while ((feature = containerElements.Next()) != null) {
            var symbol = geoFtr.Renderer.SymbolByFeature[feature];
            var symbMarker = geoFtr.Renderer.SymbolByFeature[feature] as ISimpleMarkerSymbol;
```

the symbMarker is my symbol, it is of type I symbol but I casted it to ISimpleMarkerSymbol for other purposes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access symbology from a single feature .
The symbology renderer is defined at the level of the layer.

You can set the renderer from the [IGeoFeatureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeoFeatureLayer_Interface/00120000052t000000/), you access this by casting from IFeaturelayer.

More info see: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_layers_and_renderers/000100000468000000/

Comment: The link you have provided is full of information, but I cant find anything on schematic layers. they are layers, but I cant cast a schematic layer to an IGeoFeatureLayer. any suggestions ? I am trying to scale and rotate the symbols

Comment: I'am sorry, I don't know anything about schematic layers, i just assume they work the same way as regular layers.

Comment: They do to some extent. Thanks for your help though, I am sure someone else will have on how to control the symbols for those schematic layers